# SQL Query error help to solve

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create database MC120203207

create table employee
(
    id varchar (15) not null, 
    Name nvarchar (50) not null,
    Address nvarchar (75) not null,
    DoB date not null, 
    primary key(id)
);

create table Payroll
(
    id varchar (10)not null,
    Allowances float not null,
    Msalary float not null,
    References employee(id),
    primary key(id)
);

create table Hourly
( 
    id varchar (10)not null,
    HourlyRate float not null,
    References employee(id),
    primary key (id)
);

Create Table Projects 
(
    id varchar (10) not null,
    Code int (10) not null, 
    Description varchar (50) not null, 
    primary key (code)
);

Insert into employee (id, name, address, DoB) values ('MC120203207', 'Aurang Zeb Khan', 'Bannu', 27-02-1980)
Insert into employee (id, name, address, DoB) values ('BC120201875', 'Alam Zeb Khan', 'Bannu', 02-08-1992)
```

There is a problem in the Query, please help to solve it... it shows the message

> Msg 142, Level 15, State 2, Line 0
>   Incorrect syntax for definition of the 'TABLE' constraint.
>
> Msg 142, Level 15, State 2, Line 0
>   Incorrect syntax for definition of the 'TABLE' constraint.

Comment: You're not defining any **column** in `Payroll` or `Hourly` that references `employee.id` !! Try:  `employeeId varchar(15) references employee(id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a **column** in your tables that references `employee.id` - just writing `references employee(id)` alone is **not enough!**.

Pay attention to the fact that the foreign key column that you define in `Payroll` (or `Hourly`) **must have** the **exact same** datatype as the column you're referencing.

Try this:

```
create table Payroll
(
    id varchar (10)not null,
    Allowances float not null,
    Msalary float not null,
    employeeId varchar(15) references employee(id),
    primary key(id)
);
```

Comment: you are right @marc_s & also if you want to make your all the tables in these MC120203207 DB then you need to write "use MC120203207" after first line.

Comment: It worked and "query executed successfully"
create table Payroll
(
    id varchar (10)not null,
    Allowances float not null,
    Msalary float not null,
    employeeId varchar(15) references employee(id),
    primary key(id)
);

create table Hourly
(
   id varchar (10)not null,
   HourlyRate float not null,
   employeeId varchar(15) references employee(id),
   primary key (id)
);